# Config has been ruined by me

Tags: c#, wcf

I have totally stuffed my app.config file for my test web service I am trying to write.

The error I am getting now is this:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'LocationService.ILocationServices' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

I have a domain, www.mydomain.com, to get the files there, I simply ftp them to ftp.mydomain.com - root.

My config file has this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="CraigsService.LocationServices">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CraigsService.ILocationServices">
          <identity>
            <dns value="www.mydomain.com" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://www.mydomain.com/CraigsService/LocationServices/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

All my classes are in the CraigsService namespace.

My interface is declared:

```
public interface ILocationServices
```

But I can't get this to work. Should my domain name be in App.Config? I have tried Localhost (How else do you debug locally?).

For the life of me, I can't spot the issue. Hope someone can assist.

**EDIT: The problem was that I was deploying a website and a my web service into the same folder**, I think! After deleting all files, and redeploying, it seems to be OK. But, now I need to create a sub folder, /services/, and deploy the service into that folder. What has to be changed in the App.Config?

If I simply change the folder to /services/ where I deploy, I get:

**The type 'CraigsService.LocationServices', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.**

Comment: Depending on how big your service is, consider creating a brand new service and copy and pasting your code over (unless of course you did anything extravagent to your `app.config` in the first instance) :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a setting wrong on my hosting company control panel. The folder I was splitting to want set up as an iis application root.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have changed the references that point to namespace-qualified names of .Net types to include the namespace "CraigsService" instead of the actual namespace of the contract interface and the type that implements the service contract. Either change the name in the config xml and @ServiceHost directive or move the types to the new namespace. For instance, you could probably change

```
<% @ServiceHost Service=”CraigsService.LocationServices” ...
```

to

```
<% @ServiceHost Service=”TheActualNameSpace.LocationServices” ...
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where to change that. But, it works if I deploy to the root of my domain. As soon as I deploy to /services/, it fails. Si, I'm not sure how the namespace is effecting that?

Comment: @craig  The directive is in the .svc file. You may need to right click and view markup